# How can I handle gems with a portable JRuby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, portability, gems-in-a-jar

We're using Ruby scripts for certain parts of a build. To execute them, we're using JRuby ( the complete jar ), and so far we haven't made use of any gems outside the stdlib. If for example, I would want use three gems from github, how would I approach this?

I know of [Nick Sieger's Gems-in-a-jar](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2009/01/10/jruby-1-1-6-gems-in-a-jar) article, but it's from 2009. Is it still the accepted way of doing this or did JRuby introduce another method of achieving the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gems-in-a-jar, or you can use [Warbler](http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/) to bundle JRuby and all your gems into a single executable jar.